# What does "& _" mean in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I'm copying some query statements from a legacy VB app to a C# app. I am not familiar with VB, although looking at it makes me want a VB (Victoria Bitter). I have come across queries constructed like this:

```
*SELECT dp_duckbill_accounts.platypus_no AS duckbill, t_accounts.name AS Name " & _ 
"FROM t_accounts INNER JOIN dp_duckbill_accounts ON  t_accounts.account_no = dp_duckbill_accounts.account_no " & _
"ORDER BY dp_duckbill_accounts.platypus_no*
```

The "& _" give me pause. If it was just "&" I would think it corresponds to "+" in C# to concatenate strings. But what in the world is the point of the underscore? Note the ampersand and the underscore are separated by a space.

Comment: It should be noted that [implicit line continuation was added in VB.NET 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/we86c8x2(v=vs.100).aspx#implicitlinecontinuation), making the _ obsolete for many cases.

Comment: @j.i.h.: Wow, only 22 years in the making.

Comment: I still use it in principal...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The underscore is the [line continuation character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It allows the concatenation to include a different line. Like so:

```
x = "Hello " & "World"

x = "Hello " & _
    "World"

'this won't compile (pre vb.net 2010, anyway)
    x = "Hello " & 
    "World"
```

[Line Continuation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[How to: Break and Combine Statements in Code (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ba9sxbw4.aspx)

Comment: @BradChristie I added another link, but that one's nicer, I'll add it to my answer too, thanks!

Comment: VB.net 10 did away with the need for underscore line continuations http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/04/vb_underscores

Comment: I want to note, however, that I always had better luck writing LINQ queries in VS 2010 and 2012 with underscores... seems like the parser they used chokes up a bit when you don't.

Answer (score 10):

`_` means continue the statement on the following line.

so `... & _` means continue concatenating the string on the following line.

```
text = "One line string"
text = "Two line " & _
       "string"
```

Answer (score 3):

That is just a line continuation character that lets you continue to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

& -  is used for string concatenation in same line. 
*example -  sConcatenatedString  = "First" & "Second"*

& _ - is used For string concatenation in different lines.
*example - sConcatenatedString = "First" &_ 
                                  "Second"*