# Insert data to a table from VB6: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert data from VB6 to SQL Server. I am trying it with ADODB.Command but when executing the function it sends me this error.

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB
>   status value, if available. No work was done.

I already made the table with the same types of data but it still shows this error

This is my code

```
Dim strSQL As String
   strSQL = "INSERT INTO FacturasPendientes (IdFactura,FechaFactura,CodigoProveedor,NombreProveedor," & _
                           "TotalFactura,FechaVencimiento,DiasDescuento,DescProntoPago,Pagado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
   Dim CmdCont As ADODB.Command
     Set CmdCont = New ADODB.Command
        With CmdCont
            Set .ActiveConnection = Cnn
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandText = strSQL
            .Prepared = True
        End With
            'Creamos los Parametros
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("IdFactura", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TxtFactura.Text)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("FechaFactura", adDate, adParamInput, 50, dtpFactura.Value)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("CodigoProveedor", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TxtCodigoProveedor.Text)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("NombreProveedor", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtProveedor.Text)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("TotalFactura", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, m_importe3)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("FechaVencimiento", adDate, adParamInput, FechaFinal)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("DiasDescuento", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtDias.Text)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("DescProntoPago", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtDescuento.Text)
            CmdCont.Parameters.Append CmdCont.CreateParameter("Pagado", adInteger, adParamInput, 2, 0)

     CmdCont.Execute
```

Update

I have changed the way to insert the data but now trying to insert the data sends me the error

Incorrect syntax near '12'

```
query = "INSERT INTO FacturasPendientes (IdFactura,FechaFactura,CodigoProveedor,NombreProveedor,TotalFactura,FechaVencimiento,DiasDescuento,DescProntoPago,Pagado) " & _
"Values(" & TxtFactura.Text & ",CONVERT (DATETIME, " & Format(dtpFactura.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & "',102), " & _
"" & TxtCodigoProveedor.Text & " ," & txtProveedor.Text & "," & m_importe3 & "," & _
"CONVERT (DATETIME, '" & Format(FechaFinal, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & "',102),'" & txtDias.Text & "','" & txtDescuento.Text & "','" & chkPago.Value & "')"

Cnn.Execute query
```

Comment: Too few question marks in `(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)` ...

Answer (score 1):

If you write your query like this - problems become apparent:

```
INSERT INTO FacturasPendientes 
(
  IdFactura,
  FechaFactura,
  CodigoProveedor,
  NombreProveedor,
  "& _
  "TotalFactura,FechaVencimiento,DiasDescuento,DescProntoPago,Pagado
) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

The `"& _` is your first problem. Your double quotes don't appear to close properly.

Following the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079973/insert-data-to-a-table-from-vb6-multiple-step-ole-db-operation-generated-errors#comment104405342_59083854) by [@eagle275](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12183614/eagle275), which led me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548848/what-does-mean-in-vb), it seems to me that you should be doing something like (pseudocode):

```
SQL_String := " INSERT INTO FacturasPendientes (IdFactura, FechaFactura, ";
SQL_String := SQL_String + "CodigoProveedor, NombreProveedor, ";
SQL_String := SQL_String + "TotalFactura, FechaVencimiento, DiasDescuento, ";
SQL_String := SQL_String + "DescProntoPago, Pagado) "
SQL_String := SQL_String + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
```

That's what you appear to have been trying to do with the `& _` piece, but I just don't think your SQL string is constructed properly.

Not sure about VB6 - is the `;` required or not in VB6 queries like this?

When I was doing this sort of thing, I would then run something like this (again pseudocode):

```
Print_line("\n\n" = SQL_String + "\n\n");
```

And then I'd copy and paste the output from the `Print_line` function to the database server CLI (Command Line Interface - or possibly a GUI tool) to ensure that the query actually produced sensible results before moving on.

It's important when writing SQL to do some formatting as you go - this becomes more important **exponentially** as the number of lines in your SQL increases - it's very easy to become confused (never happened to me though! :-), Ahem...) with all the brackets &c. Above is the way I do it - 2 spaces (**never tabs!**) per nesting level. Find your own style and stick to it!

EDIT in response to the OP's edit (edit no. 3 in the list):

Again, I'm no VB6 expert, but I've noticed a couple of things.

```
query = 

"INSERT INTO FacturasPendientes (IdFactura,FechaFactura,CodigoProveedor,NombreProveedor,TotalFactura,FechaVencimiento,DiasDescuento,DescProntoPago,Pagado) "
 & _
"Values(" & TxtFactura.Text &                       
", CONVERT (DATETIME, " & Format(dtpFactura.Value,  <<== Missing an & here?
"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & 
"',102), " & _
"" & TxtCodigoProveedor.Text & " ," & txtProveedor.Text & "," & m_importe3 & "," & _
"CONVERT (DATETIME, '" & Format(FechaFinal, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & "',102),'" &      <<== why "', 102'" - single quotes?
txtDias.Text & "','" & txtDescuento.Text & "','" & chkPago.Value & "')"                <<== you're treating numeric (INT?) as text
```

There's no `12` in the text of your query, but there is `102`. Maybe to do with this `<<== why "', 102'"` - why are you treating 102 (what should be an INTEGER or at least a numeric of some sort) as a string?

Did you try what I suggested and use the `Print_Line()` function (whatever the VB6 equivalent is?) to print out the SQL string and run it directly on the CLI client (mysql, MySQL Workbench)? If you found my answer helpful, you can mark it as such.

Comment: he has 9 columns to fill - and 9 parameters .. it doesn't make sense to concatenate 5 parameters into 1 - the &_ is there to split the sql-string into 2 parts

Comment: quite possible - I highly suggest OP "digs" out the real Ado errors ...to see what went wrong

Comment: @eagle275 , As I said, I'm not a VB6 person. Even so, it seems to me that the query as constructed is problematic - the double quotes don't match which (from my programming days many moons ago) is a no-no! My reading of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548848/what-does-mean-in-vb) is that the OP is putting this VB6 construct in the middle of an SQL string - that's the problem! I've also edited my answer - lemme know what you think!

Comment: looks better .. on a quick look for ways around the errors I found similar solutions in building the SQL-String over multiple lines ...

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments, sorry if I can not explain well, my English is a bad thing, I have made a modification but now it sends me a different error

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you edit your code according to the example

```
Dim Conn1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd1 As ADODB.Command
Dim Param0 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim Param1 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim Rs1 As ADODB.Recordset

' Create and Open Connection Object.
Set Conn1 = New ADODB.Connection
Conn1.ConnectionString = "DSN=Biblio;UID=admin;PWD=;"
Conn1.Open

' Create Command Object.
Set Cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
Cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn1
Cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Authors (name, refcode) VALUES (?,?)"

' Create Parameter Objects.
Set Param0 = Cmd1.CreateParameter(, advarchar, adParamInput, 50)
Set Param1 = Cmd1.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, 5)
Param0.Value = "Twain, Mark"
Param1.Value = 5
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Param0
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Param1
Set Param0 = Nothing
Set Param1 = Nothing

' Open Recordset Object.
Set Rs1 = Cmd1.Execute()
```